# making a .then() function return a promise to be used by another function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

I am using this native script firebase plugin, which makes me use this function:

```
getValue() {
     var value;
     firebase.getValue('/companies')
         .then(result => {
             console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
             value = result;
             return result;

         })
         .catch(error => {
             console.log("Error: " + error);
             return error;
         });
     return value;
 }
```

If I import it in another file and use it like this:

`var myValue = this.myFirebaseService.getValue();`

If I run it the first time it returns undefined but the second time it returns the value.

My question is how do I make the firebase function return a promise so I can make my second statement wait for it.

Comment: If your environment supports it use aync/await

Comment: `firebase.getValue()` already returns Promise. What you are not doing is returning that promise from `getValue()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firebase function you're referring to is returning a promise. That's why you can use `.then` and `.catch` after calling the getValue function.

If you return the firebase promise from `getValue()`, like this:

```
getValue(){
  return firebase.getValue('/companies');
}
```

You'll be able to call `getValue()` whenever you like, but you'll have to execute the code after `getValue()` (which is a promise) is resolved. Like so:

```
getValue().then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

I would read up on promises if you don't understand this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `myValue` after the result has been received from the `then` block.

Something like this:

```html
var myValue;

function getValue() {
  return firebase.getValue('/companies');
}

myValue = getValue().then(result => {
    const value = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(value);
    return value;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks...but what if i want to use it in another file.
lets say i want import this function in another file and use the value it returns

Comment: be sure to import the second file so that the function invoked within the `then` doesnt return undefined ;)

Comment: your `function getValue() {` didnt return the promise so `myValue = ` will always be undefined. might wanna update your answer ... `return firebase.getValue(...`

Comment: it returns undefined the first time.

Comment: @MilesStanfield Thank you for pointing it out. Updated the answer. StelDare - Check updated answer and follow what versvs says

Comment: This is ugly. Why not just use the returned promise and set the variable value in next then() in chain?

Comment: How can `init()` be called after a return ?

Comment: @nashcheez am importing the getValue() function into another file to use it there.